# OpenGL GLSL GLUT conflict

Tags: opengl, glsl, static-libraries

Ok, I am trying to make an OpenGL Application to use a Fragment Shader.  I need to get some variables into the fragment shader using `glUniform`.

I've seen some examples that look like this:

```
static PFNGLSHADERSOURCEARBPROC glShaderSourceARB;
```

they have like 10 of those. When I put them in, it says, `previous declaration of glShaderSourceARB`, or `glShaderSourceARB was declared 'extern' and then later 'static'`.

When I DON'T put it in, every time I use `glShaderSourceARB`, I get an `Undefined Reference to glShaderSourceARB`.

HOW is this possible?  It gets mad at me for declaring it twice, but if I take out 1 declaration, it says its not declared at all. Can someone explain how this is supposed to work?

Comment: Wow, what places are you looking? `GL_ARB_shader_objects` is not something you want to mess around with. Use core GLSL, any introductory OpenGL 3.2 tutorial should set you on the proper path.

Comment: you are at definitly wrong place.. wrong tutorial or wrong resource for starting with OpenGl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, your problem stems from lack of knowledge about C storage and scope qualifiers.

`static` in the global scope means: This symbol is visible to only the compilation unit its in and only that compilation unit. Other compilation units may have static symbols of the same name, but those are their own private symbols as well and they don't interfere.

`extern` means, that the symbol it refers to is defined *and* exposed (i.e. not `static`) somewhere else unit. You normally use it in headers. While it's certainly possible to write `extern static` this usually makes little sense to do.

Now what you did was introducing a new, global symbol with `static` scope, while the header already declared a not `static` symbol of the same name to exist. And the compiler tells you "sorry, this name is already taken; but your symbol doesn't match the extern declaration, so get lost."

However with just a `extern` declaration, but no actual definition of the symbol, the linker will at the end tell you: "There are a few parts missing, where is `xyz`, did nobody actually define it; everybody is referring to it (extern), but nobody actually provides it."

Okay, so should you define `glShaderSourceARB` as non-static then? **No!**

Because having that symbol around does not suffice. You also have to initialize it to something. For that you use `glXGetProcAddress` or `wglGetProcAddress`. You have to call that with the function name, for each and every symbol. And because in Windows the function addresses may depend on the active OpenGL context you have to put those symbols into *thread local storage* and reinitialize them everytime wglMakeCurrent is called.

What you really should do is get yourself a library that does all this tedious work drop it into your program and no longer think about it. Like GLEW, available at http://glew.sourceforge.net – read the documentation carefully, follow each step and things will work (if you follow the documentation). A word of recommendation: Embedding GLEW statically simplifies program distribution.

Comment: Wow someone already did all of this!  I'm now reading up on GLEW, thanks

Comment: @user3624590: GLEW has it's issues though. Another loader, which I came to like very much is [`glLoadGen`](https://bitbucket.org/alfonse/glloadgen/overview). Actually its a code generator with which you can select which OpenGL profile exactly you want to use in your program. It then creates appropriate a header and C source file which you add to your program.

Comment: I looked that up!  that would be really convenient, although setting up Lua has been pretty tricky.  Luckily glew is working for now

Answer (score 1):

You evidently have a header where the function signatures are declared, but you don't have any library linked, which would actually contain the functions (that is the `undefined reference` error).

In Windows, the library does not contain shader functions (only functions up to OpenGL 1.1) and some third party library such as GLEW or GLEE is a must. You can also see how [MiniShader](http://www.stud.fit.vutbr.cz/~xpolok00/proj/MiniShader.h) is implemented (it does what GLEW / GLEE do, except it is optimized for minimal code size, such as in 4k intros).

In Linux, just linking with `-lGL` could help linking with the OpenGL library abd thus avoiding `undefined reference`s (if not, then use GLEW just as well).

Comment: I'm on Windows, so after reading some on GLEW I guess I don't need to find these functions by myself